# PHPBB3.0 <IF S_GROUP - условие для отображения

Tags: php7, phpbb

PHPBB 3.0
Для создания условия отображения для пользователей, состоящих в группах, внёс изменение в includes/functions.php

```
    if ( !function_exists('group_memberships') )
{
    include_once($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_user.'.$phpEx);
}

$groups = group_memberships(false,$user->data['user_id']);
foreach ($groups as $grouprec)
{
    $template->assign_vars(array(
        'S_GROUP_' . $grouprec['group_id'] => true
  ));
}
```

В файлах шаблонов используется следующая конструкция:

```
<!-- IF S_GROUP_ID == 12 or S_GROUP_ID == 5 -->Текст для пользователей, состоящих в группах 12 и 5 <!-- ENDIF -->
```

Однако, дебаггер начал ловить ошибки:
/includes/functions.php
Строка: 5462

```
[PHP Warning] Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Строка 5462:

```
foreach ($groups as $grouprec)
```